# How to restrict user access to subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was hoping for some advice on how to restrict user access to subdomains.
The subdomains should only be accessed with a valid `$_GET` param, like `www.domain.com/index.php?mykey=12345`

I have a Yii backend which controls these keys, but cant find a good way to restrict access.  I have tried an `.htaccess` rule to pass all traffic to index.php, which then does something in the backend controller like

```
file_get_contents('/var/www/'. $requested_file) ;
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/index.php/$1
```

Obvious security risk I know.  It sort of works, but has problems with images as it passes ALL traffic through `f_g_c().`

Hopefully there is a more straightforward way of doing this.

**Edit**: Ideally I would not like to make the presence of the back-end visible to users.  Hence why I'm not using the obvious straightforward methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming that you're using apache)

If you want it to ignore images, you could add a few conditions to your rule so it looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpe?g|gif|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/index.php/$1
```

This makes it so the rule won't be applied if the requested URI has a certain extension. Also, when your RewriteRule has a target that starts with **http://**, it inherently redirects the browser instead of internally rewriting the URI. This means when someone enters http://www.domain.com/some-path in their browser's URL address bar, it gets redirected and their address bar now says http://www.domain.com/index.php/some-path . If you remove the domain bit, it'll get internally rewritten (the condition is to prevent looping):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```